# Rails model to_s method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails application there is a relationship defined between Products and Categories. Each product can have different categories.

I am displaying the product's category this way:

```
<p>
    <strong>Categories:</strong>
    <%= @product.categories.join(", ") unless @product.categories.nil? %>
</p>
```

And my `Category` model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    def to_s
        @name
    end
end
```

However, in the show page, the categories are displayed like this:

```
Categories: #<Category:0x007f2bf515b148>, #<Category:0x007f2bf515aef0>, #<Category:0x007f2bf515ac98>
```

Why is the `to_s` method not working? How can I solve this?

Comment: What you want to show? Product category name?

Comment: No need for the @ symbol if you want to show category name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `@product.categories` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, not an array. Therefore the method `join` is the one implemented inside the relation class, not the `Array#join`.

You should implicitly cast the list to array

```
<%= @product.categories.to_a.join(", ") unless @product.categories.nil? %>
```

or you should pay a little bit more attention of what you really need, avoid loading the entire objects and obtain a more efficient result.

```
<%= @product.categories.pluck(:name).join(", ") unless @product.categories.nil? %>
```

It is worth mentioning you can use the `to_sentence` method.

```
<%= @product.categories.pluck(:name).to_sentence unless @product.categories.nil? %>
```

Moreover, the `.nil?` check is completely useless because `@product.categories` is a relation and will never be nil.

And if you really want to write better code, you avoid implementing your logic in the view and you rely on helpers and models.

```
class Product
  def category_names
    categories.pluck(:name)
  end
end

module ProductsHelper
  def product_categories_list(product)
    product.category_names.to_sentence
  end
end

<%= product_categories_list(@product) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

try do define method like:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    def to_s
        self.name
    end
end
```

Comment: There is no difference between passing `self` or not. `self` for readers is implicit and redundant in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

To access your attribute, if it is a column in your table, you should not use the @attr_name, as they are not stored as instance variables.

Try just to redefine your `to_s` method like following:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_s
    name
  end
end
```

It is really interesting the way this behaves:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_s
    nil
  end
end
```

Then

```
"#{Role.first}"
 => "#<Role:0x00000007a39f88>"
```

But:

```
Role.first.to_s
=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

I have conducted an experiment to locate the problem and I suggest you look at results.

This is output of a `pry` REPL. It's not quite a Rails model but it points out the issue.

What I did: I defined a new class and instructed it to output the names af any non-existent methods that are called on it. This is a handy trick to determine implicit calls on your classes.

```
[1] pry(main)> class Hi
[1] pry(main)*   def method_missing(sym)
[1] pry(main)*     puts sym
[1] pry(main)*   end  
[1] pry(main)* end  
=> :method_missing
[2] pry(main)> a = [Hi.new, Hi.new]
=> [#<Hi:0x0000000405b028>, #<Hi:0x0000000405afd8>]
[3] pry(main)> a.join
to_str
to_str
to_ary
to_str
to_ary
=> "#<Hi:0x0000000405b028>#<Hi:0x0000000405afd8>"
```

It's not `to_s`. It's `to_str`, apparently, that is called.